# MySQL show results if any of the combination match

Tags: mysql, sql

Lets say a user has a search form where he searches for properties. Lets say he selects:

```
Location : ABC
Price Range : 1 million - 5 millions
No. of Bedrooms Range : 5 - 12
State : XYZ
County : PQR
Category: MNO
```

There is a very slim chance of matching all the fields he selected to yield result from the database. so using `AND` in `WHERE` condition doesn't seem effective here. what I want is -

1. If all selection matched then no problem show the result
2. If location, price range, state matched then show the result as well
3. if location, no of bedrooms, category, state matched then show the result as well
4. and so on....if any of the combination match then show the result

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about filtering the table for records that match on any search term and sorting the results in descending order of the number of matching terms:

```
SELECT   *,
         (Location = 'ABC')
       + (Price BETWEEN 1000000 AND 5000000)
       + (Bedrooms BETWEEN 5 AND 12)
       + (State = 'XYZ')
       + (County = 'PQR')
       + (Category = 'MNO')
           AS relevance
FROM     my_table
WHERE    (Location = 'ABC')
      OR (Price BETWEEN 1000000 AND 5000000)
      OR (Bedrooms BETWEEN 5 AND 12)
      OR (State = 'XYZ')
      OR (County = 'PQR')
      OR (Category = 'MNO')
HAVING   relevance >= ?   -- specify the minimum number of matching terms here
ORDER BY relevance DESC
LIMIT    ?                -- specify the maximum number of matching records here
```

Comment: I tried this, it yielded almost all records. There are around total `883` records, the query returned `858` records, which seems pretty irrelevant

Comment: @Sharmila: You could add a `HAVING` clause to restrict the results to only those which match on more than *n* terms and/or a `LIMIT` clause to restrict the results to the best *n* matches.

Comment: Much easier to read and maintain, generally a lot cleaner than the other answers, you got my vote!

Comment: @eggyal, thanks for your help. But still its not working, no matter what I choose in the search form it just gives same 14 results

Answer (score 3):

You would want to make numerous conditions in your WHERE clause

```
WHERE (Location AND price AND Bedrooms AND State AND County AND Category)
OR (Location AND Price AND State)
OR (Location AND Bedrooms AND Category AND State)
OR (...)
...
```

This allows for any combination of data you want to be valid to return data.

Answer (score 2):

Similar to eggyals solution, but to just bring back the rows you care about. Not tested so please excuse any typos:-

```
SELECT Sub2.*
FROM (SELECT MAX(
CASE WHEN Location = 'ABC' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END +
CASE WHEN Price BETWEEN 1000000 AND 5000000 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END +
CASE WHEN Bedrooms BETWEEN 5 AND 12 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END +
CASE WHEN State = 'XYZ' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END +
CASE WHEN County = 'PQR' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END +
CASE WHEN Category = 'MNO' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS MatchCount
FROM     my_table a
WHERE    (Location = 'ABC')
      OR (Price BETWEEN 1000000 AND 5000000)
      OR (Bedrooms BETWEEN 5 AND 12)
      OR (State = 'XYZ')
      OR (County = 'PQR')
      OR (Category = 'MNO'))Sub1
INNER JOIN (SELECT a.*,
CASE WHEN Location = 'ABC' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END +
CASE WHEN Price BETWEEN 1000000 AND 5000000 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END +
CASE WHEN Bedrooms BETWEEN 5 AND 12 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END +
CASE WHEN State = 'XYZ' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END +
CASE WHEN County = 'PQR' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END +
CASE WHEN Category = 'MNO' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS MatchCount
FROM     my_table a
WHERE    (Location = 'ABC')
      OR (Price BETWEEN 1000000 AND 5000000)
      OR (Bedrooms BETWEEN 5 AND 12)
      OR (State = 'XYZ')
      OR (County = 'PQR')
      OR (Category = 'MNO')) Sub2
ON Sub1.MatchCount = Sub2.MatchCount
```